# Creating a virtual camera that shows an app (override web whatsapp QR code)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera

I'm trying to override the problem of connecting to web whatsapp on a phone without a camera in order to scan the QR code.
It's probably not important but the computer runs linux.

My idea: creating a virtual device that the phone (samsung galaxy s21) will see as a camera, and in this camera there will be:

Option 1: the remote controlled desktop of the linux computer (by vnc or similar).

Option 2: the android phone will be connected by USB to the computer and it will see the desktop as a "camera".

Any other idea can be good, but it must be a synchronized whatsapp and not on an android emulator.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I am stuck in the same situation.

Comment: Unfortunately no...